# Account Search Wildcard - SugarCRM

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I'm looking for a way to do a wildcard search when searching for accounts in SugarCRM but I'm having trouble getting the queries to work properly.

Here's the build_generic_where_clause() function:

```
function build_generic_where_clause ($the_query_string) {
    $where_clauses = Array();
    $the_query_string = $this->db->quote($the_query_string);
    array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.name like '%$the_query_string%'");
    if (is_numeric($the_query_string)) {
        array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.phone_alternate like '%$the_query_string%'");
        array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.phone_fax like '%$the_query_string%'");
        array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.phone_office like '%$the_query_string%'");
    }

    $the_where = "";
    foreach($where_clauses as $clause)
    {
        if(!empty($the_where)) $the_where .= " or ";
        $the_where .= $clause;
    }


    $log = fopen('1.txt', "a");
    fwrite($log, $the_where . "\n");

    return $the_where;
}
```

I only changed `array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.name like '%$the_query_string%'");` to include the percentage signs on either side of the_query_string.

Here's processSearchForm() from view.list.php:

```
 function processSearchForm(){


        if(isset($_REQUEST['query']))
        {
            // we have a query
            if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && preg_match('/action=EditView/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { // from EditView cancel
                $this->searchForm->populateFromArray($this->storeQuery->query);
            }
            else {
                $this->searchForm->populateFromRequest();
            }

            $where_clauses = $this->searchForm->generateSearchWhere(true, $this->seed->module_dir);

            if (count($where_clauses) > 0 )$this->where = '('. implode(' ) AND ( ', $where_clauses) . ')';
            $GLOBALS['log']->info("List View Where Clause: $this->where");

            $log = fopen('1.txt', "a");
            fwrite($log, $this->where . "\n");

        }
        if($this->use_old_search){
            switch($view) {
                case 'basic_search':
                    $this->searchForm->setup();
                    $this->searchForm->displayBasic($this->headers);
                    break;
                 case 'advanced_search':
                    $this->searchForm->setup();
                    $this->searchForm->displayAdvanced($this->headers);
                    break;
                 case 'saved_views':
                    echo $this->searchForm->displaySavedViews($this->listViewDefs, $this->lv, $this->headers);
                   break;
            }
        }else{
            echo $this->searchForm->display($this->headers);
        }
    }
```

Note that I only added the log file write to catch the $this->where. If I use the searchbox to find an account such as "Newbold" as well as "New York Design", I only get "Newbold" as a result and my log file reads `(accounts.name like 'new%')`. So the first percentage sign is being removed somehow or another, I believe in the processSearchForm() somewhere. It's tough to figure out if that's the case or if the culprit lies elsewhere. I find this code to be a bit convoluted and all over the place, but this is the only customization I need done. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm hoping to do the very same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**You should be able to do this without changing any code. When you're searching from the Accounts list view, simply add the wildcards to your search in the form. Put '%$the_query_string%' in the search form.**

If you're wanting to programmatically use a wildcard to search for records, you can do something like the following.

```
<?php

$filter = 'ABC%'; // account names that start with 'ABC'
$account = BeanFactory::getBean('Accounts');
$accounts = $account->get_list("", "accounts.name like '".$filter."'");

foreach ($accounts['list'] as $account)
{
    // do something with $account
}
```

get_list() will pull what you need. One thing to note, get_list() will only return the numbers of records that you have your list views to return. So if your list views only show 20 records, get_list() will return up to 20 records. If you want to get all results, use get_full_list().